# When to use NuGet vs adding project reference

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I develop with Visual Studio. I have a class library that contains code common to many products I develop, and is now in use by 15+ solutions. I do [LOB apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_business) for my non-software company.

I've been adding this class library project directly to the solutions of all the solutions that need to use it. But I've been using [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuget) to pull in many 3rd party packages and I really like its way of doings things. I'm thinking about adding this utility library as a NuGet package in our own repository rather than adding it directly as a project reference in the solution.

Is this a good idea? What criteria should I use to determine when to use NuGet vs when not to for internal class libraries? I realize that some might think this is an opinion based question, but I'm looking for specifically what criteria you'd use to decide rather than opinions about which is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal libraries that used and worked on by multiple teams can be exposed as Nuget packages. This way, multiple teams can work on the library, and each of them can update to a version as and when needed by that particular team.